# How can somebody access an AWS EC2 instance over the internet, if it´s located in a private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipv4, subnet

**Thanks for help in advance.**

I am actually getting startet with AWS and i am working out some testcases to provide further information to my company, how usable AWS is. After intensively working on getting the basic knowledge in AWS in the last 3 weeks (EC2, S3, IAM, SSO ...), i have reached a point where I lack the advanced background knowledge to further configure the instances.

**Short description:**

Naturally i want to make a secure design of the whole environment and this led me to think about, how i can use EC2-instances in a safe way. I thought it will not be the best solution to launch the instance directly in a public subnet.

Actually i tried to figure out a way for a more safe design and came to this draft / conclusion:

I build up a VPC with 2x private and 2x public subnets.
Each pair of subnets is located in one availability zone in the region `eu-central-1 (Frankfurt)` for redundancy.

[image]

The instance is located in the private subnet `testcase-subnet-private1-eu-central-1a`. Therefore i provide access to the public subnet `testcase-subnet-public1-eu-central-1a` in the routing-table of the private subnet by providing the `IPv4-CIDR` of `testcase-subnet-public1-eu-central-1a`.

Question (updated):
**How can somebody access an AWS EC2 instance over the internet, if it´s located in a private subnet?**

Comment: Your public subnet presumable has an IGW (otherwise it would not be public). Additionally you need a NGW and route the traffic from the private subnet towards the internet 0.0.0.0/0 to that NGW. Do you want the internet to reach your instance or do you want your instance to reach the internet (or both)?

Comment: I am confused. You say that you launched an Amazon EC2 instance in a private subnet, but then you are asking how to "connect the instance to the Internet". Are you asking how software running on the EC2 instance can access the Internet, or are you asking how somebody on the Internet can access the instance?

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

The question would be, how somebody can access the instance on the Internet.

On the instance side I would only allow outgoing traffic (and response traffic). I would define that via the security group.

Comment: @luk2302, thanks for the hint. I will learn about NAT-gateways with the help of the AWS documentation and then try to apply it to solve the problem.

Comment: *"how somebody can access the instance on the Internet. On the instance side I would only allow outgoing traffic (and response traffic)"* - those two once again are two very different things, do you want someone to reach the instance or do you only want the instance to reach the internet?

Comment: I would need both ways (someone should reach the instance and the instance should reach the internet, but only for autodesk account sign-in).

Comment: at that point it should be really be in a public subnet with proper security groups that only expose e.g. port 443.